# Finding the expected value of a function of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm having troubles with finding marginal density functions and expected values in my probability theory class. I was hoping someone would be able to walk me through the solution to this question (I have the answer, I just don't understand how to get to it).

The question:
$$f(y_1, y_2)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{1}{y_1}&& 0\leq y_2 \leq y_1 \leq 1\\0&& \mathrm{elsewhere}\end{array}\right.$$
Find $\mathbf{E}(Y_1-Y_2)$.

The answer is $1/4$ and I understand that I have to first find the marginal density functions and use them to find $\mathbf{E}(Y_1)$ and $\mathbf{E}(Y_2)$ but I can't even do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I edited the question because it wasn't clear. Please edit if something is not right. Try to use LaTeX in the site, so everybody can understand you correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I will take note of that for next time! Wasn't sure how to format.

Comment: Recall that $f_{y_{1}}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{2}$. Thus part the only hard part is find the region to integrate over. This is easier if you draw picture of the region of the support for joint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Did, you do not have to find the marginals to find $E(Y_1)$ and $E(Y_2)$.

But we show how to  find the (marginal) distribution functions. We do the marginal distribution of $Y_2$, since in my experience students would find it a little harder.

We want to "integrate out" $y_1$, so we want to find
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y_1,y_2)\,dy_1.$$
Now we must take into account of the fact that $f(y_1,y_2)$ is defined by different formulas on different parts of the world. The density function is $\frac{1}{y_1}$ if $0\le y_2\le y_1\le 1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

*Draw a picture*, placing the $y_1$-axis is the position usually occupied by the $x$-axis, and the $y_2$-axis in the usual position of the $y$-axis.

Then our joint density function "lives" on the triangle $T$ with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$. This is the part of the unit square that is below the line $y_2=y_1$.

So when we integrate out $y_1$, the variable $y_1$ travels from $y_1=y_2$ to $y_1=1$. The (marginal) density of $Y_2$ is therefore 
$$\int_{y_1=y_2}^{y_1=1} \frac{1}{y_1}\,dy_1.$$

Integrate. We get that the density function of $Y_2$ is $-\ln y_2$ for $0\lt y_2\lt 1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

**Remark:** Now we can find $E(Y_2)$ in the usual way. It can be done by integration by parts.

But this is **not** a good way of finding $E(Y_2)$. For if instead we find 
$$\int_T y_2 \frac{1}{y_1}dA,$$
we have our choice as to whether to integrate first with respect to $y_1$ or with respect to $y_2$. If we choose to integrate first with respect to  $y_2$, the result partly cancels the $\frac{1}{y_1}$, which makes life definitely easier.

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that I have to first find the marginal density functions and use them to find E(Y1) and E(Y2)

Not necessarily, the blindest application of the definition yields $$E(Y_1-Y_2)=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}(u-v)f_{(Y_1,Y_2)}(u,v)\mathrm du\mathrm dv.$$ At this point, it might help to write down $f_{(Y_1,Y_2)}$ correctly, that is, avoiding cases and conditions on the side, **as a bona fide function defined on the whole space $\mathbb R^2$**.

In the present case, **for every $(u,v)$ in $\mathbb R^2$**, $$f_{Y_1,Y_2}(u,v)=\frac1u\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt v\lt u\lt1},$$ hence  $$E(Y_1-Y_2)=\iint(u-v)\frac1u\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt v\lt u\lt1}\mathrm du\mathrm dv=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^u(u-v)\,\frac1u\,\mathrm dv\right)\mathrm du.$$ And now, surely you can finish this... (The answer $E(Y_1-Y_2)=\frac14$ is correct.)

Answer (score 0):

While @Did's answer is, as usual, perfectly correct and the most natural way of
solving the problem, an alternative approach can be used for *this* particular
density.

Let $Y_1$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and let the *conditional*
distribution of $Y_2$ given that $Y_1 = u$ be a uniform distribution on
$[0, u]$.  Then,
$$f_{Y_1,Y_2}(u,v) = f_{Y_2\mid Y_1}(v \mid u)f_{Y_1}(u) 
= \left[\frac{1}{u}\mathbf 1_{0 \leq v\leq u}\right]\mathbf 1_{0 \leq u\leq 1}
= \frac{1}{u}\mathbf 1_{0 \leq v\leq u \leq 1}$$
which is the given density. Consequently, since the *conditional mean* of $Y_2$ given $Y_1 = u$ is just $\frac 12 u$ and the (unconditional) mean of
$Y_1$ is $\frac 12$,  we have that
$$E[Y_1-Y_2] = E\left[E[Y_1-Y_2\mid Y_1]\right]
= E\left[Y_1-\frac 12 Y_1\right]
= E\left[\frac 12 Y_1\right] = \frac 14.$$

Of course, this approach depends on knowing that this particular density
has the characterization shown above, and I freely confess that I did not 
dream up this characterization *ab initio*. It is a favorite (and
familiar) example
that begins with breaking a unit-length stick into two pieces
at point $Y_1$ from the left end where $Y_1$ is uniformly distributed
on the stick, and then breaking the left-hand piece at a
$Y_2$ where $Y_2$ is uniformly distributed on the length of the
left-hand piece.